# search a regex and filter it

Tags: javascript

Hi i am try to find a variable date in a string with a regex and after this i want to save the date in a new variable my code looks like:

```
var valide =new RegExp(/\d{2}([./-])\d{2}\1\d{4}$/mg);
var text = 'lalaahfdsdfl 02.02.1989';//example
if(valide.test(text) === true){

}
```

how can i put the found date (02.02.1989) in a new variable

Answer (score 0):

You can create groups in your Regex expression (just put the values you want between parenthesis) and then [use this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432493/how-do-you-access-the-matched-groups-in-a-javascript-regular-expression) to get the specific group value.

Note, however, I think your regex is wrong... it seems you end with 1 plus 4 digits

Answer (score 0):

You can use match on a string:

```js
var valide =new RegExp(/\d{2}([./-])\d{2}\1\d{4}$/mg);
var text = 'lalaahfdsdfl 02.02.1989';//example

console.dir(text.match(valide)) // ["02.02.1989"]

if(valide.test(text) === true){

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) for that:

```js
var valide =new RegExp(/\d{2}([./-])\d{2}\1\d{4}$/mg);
var text = 'lalaahfdsdfl 02.02.1989';//example

var foundDate = text.match(valide);

console.log(foundDate);
```

Also, you can make the regex a bit simpler if you switch the `([./-])` to `([-.])`, because `-` is considered a literal match if it comes first inside a character class.

Answer (score 0):

Using REGEXP function `match` you can extract the part that match your regular expression.

After this you will get an  object. In this case i turn it into a string so you can do a lot more things with it.

```
var myDate = text.match(valide).toString();
```

Hope this helps :>

```js
var valide =new RegExp(/\d{2}([./-])\d{2}\1\d{4}$/mg);
var text = 'lalaahfdsdfl 02.02.1989';//example

if(valide.test(text) === true){
var myDate = text.match(valide).toString();
console.log(myDate)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this.
`var result = text.match(valide)`

Here is a reference for the match method [String.prototype.match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

Comment: While this may answer the question it's better to include some description on how this answer help to solve the issue. Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).